# DigitalOcean droplet zero downtime deploy

Tags: digital-ocean

I've deployed Django app in [Digitalocean **droplet**](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/droplets/).
How can I deploy a new version of the app and make the old version **still work**, while I'm pulling out from git and deploying it?
In [DigitalOcean **app**](https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/app-platform/) it works automaticaly.

Answer (score 1):

look into blue-green deployment.
(simplification)
You can basically have a symlink pointing to two directories with the source code and you make any `git pull` or updates in one of them, and then re-point the symlink when everything is ready. Your web server (apache,nginx,etc) would always be pointing to the symlink.

for example

```
# green.git/
# blue.git/
# live_symlink -> green.git


$> cd blue.git; git pull; cd ..; 
$> ln -sfn blue.git live_symlink
# live_symlink -> blue.git

$> cd green.git; git pull; cd ..; 
$> ln -sfn green.git live_symlink
# live_symlink -> green.git
```

PS: if the database changes during deployments then you need to take more things into consideration, like having database migration scripts, and make changes to the database progressively; for example, don't rename or drop columns in a single release, and instead you make one release that adds a new column with a new name, and the code accesses both the old-named and new-named columns, and on a later release you remove the old-named column and the code would only touch the new-named column.